# Angular 2 NgbModal NgbActiveModal close event modal

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm using Angular 2, I'm working with a form modal, I have two components, from one component I open the form modal this way:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { MyFormComponent } from '......./....';


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'my-component.html'
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    private anyData: any;
    private anyDataForm: any;


    constructor(
        private modalService: NgbModal
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    open() {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(MyFormComponent, { size: 'lg' });
        modalRef.componentInstance.anyDataForm = this.anyData;
    }

    possibleOnCloseEvet() { 
        //Do some actions....
    }

}
```

The open() method fires from a button on **my-component.html**

And on the Form component (the modal one) I use this for close the actual modal (from itself)

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-form-component',
    templateUrl: 'my-form-component.html'
})
export class MyFormComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    @Input() anyDataForm: any;

    constructor(
        public activeModal: NgbActiveModal
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    //Some form code...

    OnSubmit() {
        this.activeModal.close(); //It closes successfully
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
    }

}
```

What I need to do is fire some kind of "on close" event on the caller component to perform some actions in the caller only when the modal is closed. (can't use event emmiter)

Is there any way for the component opener to know when the modal close? I have not found any clear example of this.

Answer (score 38):

Try this:

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(MyFormComponent, { size: 'lg' });
modalRef.componentInstance.anyDataForm = this.anyData;

modalRef.result.then((data) => {
  // on close
}, (reason) => {
  // on dismiss
});
```

Comment: i just wanted to trigger some services on modal closed so i used finally() istead of then

Cheers @Adnan

Comment: one key thing to note here is you need to include the second callback function as well, not just the first otherwise you'll get an error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Number] at resolvePromise (zone.js:1262:1)

Answer (score 8):

On my ModalformComponent

```
 this.activeModal.close('success');
```

Then on my parent-component ListComponent

```
 this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalformComponent);
 this.modalRef.componentInstance.title = 'Add Record';
 this.modalRef.result.then((result) => {
  if ( result === 'success' ) {
     this.refreshData(); // Refresh Data in table grid
  }
}, (reason) => {
});
```

Answer (score 2):

in `MyFormComponent` you can add

```
closeModal() { this.activeModal.close( anything ); }
```

Answer (score -3):

Instead of `this.activeModal.close();`, use `this.activeModal.dismissAll()`.
It will close the popup successfully.

Comment: The OP can close the modal successfully. What was needed was to somehow listen to it closing in the code that opened it so they could run some code like updating data in it.